# ServiceConnection - Service throws NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-service, serviceconnection

In my application, it was possibly for me to establish a bluetooth connection and sending bytes with an own Service and send some bytes to the receiver.

Now I tried unsuccessfully to connect to my own server for sending a text and get an answer. For any reason, I get a NullPointerException for my Service if I try to call the sendMessage() Method..

Service:

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ClientService extends Service {
private String LOG_TAG = null;
private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
private final String url_string = "";

private int receivedUcCommand = 0;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

public void sendToServer(final String text){

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(internetAvailable()){
                try {
                    String textParam = "text1" + URLEncoder.encode(text,"UTF-8");
                    URL scriptUrl = new URL(url_string);
                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) scriptUrl.openConnection();
                    connection.setDoOutput(true);
                    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(textParam.getBytes().length);
                    OutputStreamWriter contextWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());

                    contextWriter.write(textParam);
                    contextWriter.flush();
                    contextWriter.close();


                    InputStream answerInputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                    String answer = read(answerInputStream);

                    answerInputStream.close();
                    connection.disconnect();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();

}

private String read(InputStream is){
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String currentLine;
    try {
        while((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(currentLine+"\n");
        }
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sb.toString().trim();
}
private boolean internetAvailable(){
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return ni != null && ni.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // Wont be called as service is not bound
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "In onBind");
    return mBinder;
}


public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    ClientService getService() {
        // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
        return ClientService.this;
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "In onTaskRemoved");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "In onDestroy");
}
}
```

In Activity I do this:

```
public class loggedInActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{
    public static final String mBroadcastStringAction = "com.truiton.broadcast.string";
    public static final String mBroadcastIntegerAction = "com.truiton.broadcast.integer";
    public static final String mBroadcastArrayListAction = "com.truiton.broadcast.arraylist";
    private TextView mTextView;
    private IntentFilter mIntentFilter;

    BluetoothService bService;
    ClientService cService;

    boolean btBound = false;
    boolean clientBound = false;


   // private View startButton;



    Button testButton;
    EditText et;
    static final int CAM_REQUEST = 1;
    //Button reconnectButton;

    TextView recText;







        recText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.receivedText);
        //recText.setText("KEIN ALARM");

        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        testButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.testButton);


        // This way I start and bind the service for Bluetooth, to my activity
        Intent btIntent = new Intent(this, BluetoothService.class);
        startService(btIntent);
        bindService(btIntent, btServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        //And this way I unsuccessfully trying to bind and start the ClientService for ServerConnection
        Intent clientIntent = new Intent(this, ClientService.class);
        startService(clientIntent);
        bindService(clientIntent, clientServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);


       testButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                //ATTENTION: TRYING TO SENDING TO SERVER HERE, IT THROWS ME A NULLPOINTER
                cService.sendToServer(et.getText().toString());


            }
        });
    }

 /** Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService() */
    private ServiceConnection btServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                       IBinder service) {
            // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance

            BluetoothService.LocalBinder binder = (BluetoothService.LocalBinder) service;
            bService = binder.getService();
            btBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            btBound = false;
        }
    };



    //I think it has to be to do something with that code here, but
this is the only place, where cService is defined...
    private ServiceConnection clientServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            ClientService.LocalBinder binder = (ClientService.LocalBinder) service;

cService = binder.getService();
            clientBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            clientBound = false;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

It was like I said a mistake, which only could produced by a newbie like me. I forget to sign in the  tag in the AndroidManifest.xml